# Why $24-504x+4416x^2+24(-1-2x)(1-x-x^2)^{23}\ge 0$ for $x\ge 0$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, inequality, polynomials

How can I rigorously prove that
$$24-504x+4416x^2+24(-1-2x)(1-x-x^2)^{23}\ge 0$$
for all real $x\ge 0$?

I tried using root finding algorithms but I can't come up with a rigorous proof. But I noticed that at $x=0$, the polynomial is exactly zero.

Comment: I started by noticing the first $3$ terms as a parabola have only complex roots, and also that every term is divisible by $24$. So you might try proving instead that $1-21x + 184x^2 \geq (1+2x)(1-x-x^2)^{23}$. Not sure if that helps or not, but it jumped out at me quickly.

Comment: your inequality is trivial for when $1-x-x^2<0,$ so the only interesting case is when $0\leq x\leq \dfrac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}.$

Comment: @dezdichado Could you please elaborate and post it as an answer?

Comment: my previous comment was a bit too rushed. $1-21x + 184x^2\geq 1$ only if $x\geq \dfrac{21}{184}$ and so the true interesting interval for this problem would be $[0, \dfrac{21}{184}]$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Focus only on the interval $I = \left[0, \dfrac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}\right]$, where $0\leq x^2+x\leq 1.$ As mentioned in the comments, it suffices to prove:
$$f(x) = 1-21x + 184x^2\geq (1+2x)(1-x-x^2)^{23} = g(x)$$ on $I.$
Consider the derivative of $\ln f(x)-\ln g(x):$
$$\dfrac{d}{dx}\ln\left(f(x) - g(x)\right) = \dfrac{115x^2(144x^2+124x+21)}{(1-x-x^2)(1+2x)} \geq 0.$$

So yeah, this function is minimized at $x = 0$ on the given interval and therefore
$$\ln f(x) - \ln g(x)\geq \ln f(0) - \ln g(0) = 1 - 1 = 0\implies f(x)\geq g(x).$$